# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name "setName" with signature "(Ljava.lang.String;)V" in class file Parent

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name "setName" with signature "(Ljava.lang.String;)V" in class file Parent. For below program.

```
class Parent constructor (name: String){
     var name: String = ""
     fun setName(name: String){
         this.name = name
     }
}

fun main(agrs: Array<String>) {  
    val parent = Parent("Amit")
    val parent1 = parent
    val parent2 = parent
    parent2.setName("Ajit")
    println(parent1 === parent2)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is more or less explained here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-2284 (error occurs for Java-compatibility reasons)

Fortunately, it is possible to describe a class with the same capabilities with less code thanks to the different syntactic sugars of Kotlin:

```kotlin
data class Parent(var name: String = "")
```

(a data class is like a class except that it generates the `equals` and `hashCode` functions)

If it is necessary to have more control over the `getters` and `setters` it is possible to use explicit descriptions, as documented here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters